# Generating DDL script for object without schema name baked in using DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL?

Tags: oracle, dbms-metadata

How can I generate the DDL script for my object with `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` without the schema name baked in?

With `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`:

```
CREATE TABLE "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE"
(
  "COL1"  NUMBER(10,0)
)
```

SQL Developer can do that, and I think it's also uses the DBMS_METADATA to achive this goal and generale DDL scripts.

With SQL Developer:

```
CREATE TABLE "MYTABLE"
(
  "COL1"  NUMBER(10,0)
)
```

Comment: Here's one example... http://www.myoraclesupports.com/content/how-get-ddl-statement-using-dbmsmetadatagetddl-object-without-having-object-owner-ddl

Comment: The example link no longer works, here is [an archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20101022053403/http://www.myoraclesupports.com/content/how-get-ddl-statement-using-dbmsmetadatagetddl-object-without-having-object-owner-ddl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use SET_REMAP_PARAM with the REMAP_SCHEMA option:

```
DBMS_METADATA.SET_REMAP_PARAM(th,'REMAP_SCHEMA','HR',NULL);
```

This will map the HR schema to NULL (you'll need a job handle, though); for a full example, see [metadata_api documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/metadata_api.htm)

Comment: This answer did not work for me. The answer with EMIT_SCHEMA worked though.

Answer (score 22):

I recently stumbled upon the following which allows you to get ddl without the schema name.

It looks a lot simpler than any other way I have seen so far although its not included in any Oracle documentation. I spotted it in the Statements Log in SQL Developer, which generates ddl without the schema name.

```
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'EMIT_SCHEMA', false);
```

You don't need to get handles or anything nasty just EXEC the above before calling DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL

Comment: Nice find, easier / more straightforward than my solution!

Comment: This worked for me but the accepted answer did not. (I am using oracle 19.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to removing schema(As suggested by David Norris above), if you want to remove storage and other attributes. Basically, just a plain DDL, then use below :

```
BEGIN
DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', TRUE);
DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', TRUE);
DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', FALSE);
DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'STORAGE', FALSE);      
DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'EMIT_SCHEMA', FALSE);
END;
```