# Why Oracle prepend the Schema name to created procedures?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, schema, plsqldeveloper, toad

I'm connecting to a new Oracle database with Toad.

If a create a procedure like:

```
create or replace procedure MyProc...
```

After I compile it, the name automatically is changed to

```
 SchemaName.MyProc
```

This doesn't happen in other Oracle databases where I'm doing the same test.

Is that a database configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely not a database setting - this will be a setting in TOAD somewhere

Comment: Are you sure the name is `SchemaName.MyProc` and not `MyProc` in schema `SchemaName.MyProc`? A literal dot in a procedure name is poor style.

Comment: Each procedure (function, table, index etc.) belongs to exactly one schema. Regardless of the fact if you see it or not. If you are in the schema `myschema`, then `objectname` and `myschema.objectname` are semantically equivalent. What you see in IDE as procedure definition is generated by the IDE and have a chance to be adjusted to include the schema or not. At least in db https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782278/generating-ddl-script-for-object-without-schema-name-baked-in-using-dbms-metadat

Answer (score 3):

If you open TOAD settings, you'll find it here:

1. Editor - Open/save
2. Object loading
3. if set to "Always include", you'll see owner name (SCOTT in my example)
4. if you set it to "Never include", owner name isn't visible any more

[image]